# Retain authentication via JavaScript client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, authentication, session-cookies

I have a WCF application where I make JavaScript calls to. I want to secure the web services so you have to be logged in to use it. This is easy if I have a server-side application making the requests to the WCF. If I am using a pure JavaScript / jQuery client-side app, I can authenticate fine by passing the credentials as JSON parameter, but how do I keep that client-side app logged in from that point on? Do I store a cookie? I do not want to store the credentials in the cookie of course because that is not secure. So how can I achieve this without introducing another server-side application to the mix? How do web apps achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OAuth](http://oauth.net/) is kind of the go to solution for JS API's.  [Netflix](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/Security), [Yelp](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/authentication), [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) etc. use this.

Here is an article on OAuth in [WCF](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/11/14/oauth-channel-for-wcf-restful-services.aspx)

And here is a pretty well known library for doing auth in .NET: [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use or are using ASP.Net form authentication (WCF should be running in ASP.Net compatibility mode) then there is not much to do.

If you set the form authentication ticket\cookie after your initial authentication, the cookie would be attached to every subsequent request from the browser without you writing any code. All future calls to WCF service then can be authenticated on the server using the standard ASP.Net authentication pipeline.